# I'm not sure exactly how to solve these kinds of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider $u=xu_x + yu_y + \tfrac{1}{2}(u_x^2+u_y^2)$ as a first order equation.

I have that $F_p=x+p$ and thus from $\frac{dx}{dt} = x+p$ I find $x(t) = C_1e^t-p$ where we will probably end up relabeling $C_1$ as $s$. I don't know if that is correct, but if it is and I solved the other characteristics a similar way (I can't use Lagrange-Charpit equations) then I would also find $u(x,y) = t(px+p^2)+t(qy+q^2)+C_3$.

Then I have the initial condition $u(x,0) = 1-x.$ I also don't know if I am interpreting the initial condition correctly because most material on this is poorly laid out. Is it actually supposed to be $u(x(t=0),y(t=0)=0)?$ Or is there no time to consider? But then if there isn't how am I supposed to set it equal to $u(x,0)?$

Then from here, am I trying to eliminate $p$ and $q$ in addition to the constants of integration?

Answer (score 1):

Making the change of variables

$$
\cases{
r = x+ i y\\
s = x- i y
}
$$

we obtain $u(x,y) = w(r,s)$

$$
w(r,s)=s w_s(r,s)+2 w_r(r,s) w_s(r,s)+r w_r(r,s)
$$

with solution

$$
w(r,s) = C_1 r +C_2 s+ 2C_1 C_2
$$

as can be verified by substitution. Finally

$$
u(x,y) = (C_1+C_2)x+i(C_1-C_2)y+2C_1C_2
$$

considering the initial conditions we have

$$
u(x,y) = 1-x\pm y
$$

Answer (score 0):

Simple inspection gives :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-x\pm y+1}$$
$u_x=-1$ and $u_y=\pm 1\quad\implies$

$xu_x+yu_y+\frac12(u_x^2+u_y^2)=(-1)x+(\pm 1)y+\frac12\big((-1)^2+(\pm 1)^2\big)=-x\pm y+1=u$

$u(x,0)=-x\pm 0+1=1-x$

METHOD OF CHARACTERISTICS :
$$xp+yq+\frac12(p^2+q^2)-u=F(x,y,p,q,u)=0$$
$$F_x=p \quad;\quad F_y=q \quad;\quad F_p=x+p \quad;\quad F_q=y+q \quad;\quad F_u=-1$$
Chappit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{F_p}=\frac{dy}{F_q}=\frac{du}{pF_p+qFq}=\frac{dp}{-F_x-pF_u}=\frac{dy}{-F_y-qF_u}$$

$$\frac{dx}{x+p}=\frac{dy}{y+q}=\frac{du}{p(x+p)+q(y+q)}=\frac{dp}{0}=\frac{dq}{0}$$

First characteristic equation from $dp=0\quad\implies\quad p=c_1$ .

Second characteristic equation from $dq=0\quad\implies\quad q=c_2$ .

Third characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x+c_1}=\frac{dy}{y+c_2}$
$$\frac{y+c_2}{x+c_1}=c_3$$

Fourth characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x+c_1}=\frac{dy}{y+c_2}=\frac{du}{c_1(x+c_1)+c_2(y+c_2)}=\frac{c_1dx+c_2dy-du}{c_1(x+c_1)+c_2(y+c_2)-(c_1(x+c_1)+c_2(y+c_2))}=\frac{c_1dx+c_2dy-du}{0}$
$$u-c_1x-c_2y=c_4$$

In fact, almost all the above calculus is superfluous because we are not looking for the general solution of the PDE. We are looking for a particular solution which satisfy the condition $u(x,0)=1-x$.

The fourth characteristic equation (particular case $\Phi=$constant function$=c_4$) is sufficient and leads to :
$$u(x,0)-c_1x=c_4=(1-x)-c_1x\quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}c_1=-1\\c_4=1\end{cases}$$
$$u=-x+c_2y+1$$
$$px+qy+\frac12(p^2+q^2)-u=0=-x+c_2y+\frac12((-1)^2+c_2^2)-(-x+c_2y+1)$$
$$\frac12(1+c_2^2)-1=0\quad\implies\quad c_2^2=1\quad\implies\quad c_2=\pm 1$$
$$u(x,y)=-x\pm y+1$$

Comment: Shouldn't Cauchy's method of characteristics be separate from the Lagrange-Charpit equations? I'm trying to utilize Cuachy's method.